# Function returns quadratic matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I created a function that returns a quadratic matrix whose each element is the square of either the row or the column number depending on which is greater
here's my code, but it doesn't work so far.
Anybody can help????

```
matrix_a = function(A) {A = matrix(data = 0, nrow = n, ncol = n) for (i in 1:n) {
for (j in 1:n) {
  if (i>=j) {A[i,j] = (i^2)} 
  if (i<j) {A[i,j] = (j^2)}
}} return(matrix_a)}
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of `n`?

Comment: Do I need to specify n first?

Comment: Yes. It loops from `1` to `n`. If you don't set `n` who's to say where it should end?

Comment: You need to read documentation about how to write a function. There are several problems in yours (not really considering the code inside the function): your function takes `A` as argument but first line of your function redefines `A`... using a variable `n` which you didn't define. Your function is called `matrix_a` but at the end of it you return the function itself `matrix_a`.... Apart from that, now considering the code inside, please have a look at markus answer which provides an alternative, more efficient and more `R` way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. you just had to specify `n` and return the right object at the end.

```
matrix_a = function(n) {
    A = matrix(data = 0, nrow = n, ncol = n) 
    for (i in 1:n) {
        for (j in 1:n) {
            if (i>=j) {A[i,j] = (i^2)} 
            if (i<j) {A[i,j] = (j^2)}
        }
    } 
    A
}

matrix_a(3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    9
# [2,]    4    4    9
# [3,]    9    9    9
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do

```
n <- 3
mat <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
pmax(row(mat), col(mat)) ^ 2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    9
#[2,]    4    4    9
#[3,]    9    9    9
```

Turn this into a function

```
f1 = function(n = 2) {
  mat <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
  pmax(row(mat), col(mat)) ^ 2
}

f1()
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    4    4
```

---

A second option using `outer`

```
f2 <- function(n = 3) {
  tmp <- (1:n)^2
  outer(tmp, tmp, pmax)
}
```