# R: Create efficiently a matrix with entries the maximum of column and row index

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create an (mxn)-matrix, that has as the (i,j)-entry the maximum between the row index i and the column index j, whereby i=1...m and j=1...n.

I am able to create this by for-loops, but I am sure there is a more efficient and neat solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain the same with an example?

Comment: Seems related: [Function returns quadratic matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666402/function-returns-quadratic-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `pmax()`, using `col()` and `row()` to get the indices:

```
> m = matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
> pmax(col(m), row(m))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    2    3    4
[3,]    3    3    3    4
```